# Apex Continuation is causing "Unable to restore input value state - state value missing for component..."

Tags: apex, continuous-integration

Apex Continuation is causing "Unable to restore input value state - state value missing for component..."

This happens when a continuation callout is made on the action call of a command Button and conditionally a part of a VF page is refreshed. I can provide more details around this if required.

We are trying to invoke the method simulate() on a button click in a VF page.

Here is the code:

```
// response variables (of stub generated wrapper class types)
public SalesProcessingResponse.SalesOrderSimulateResponse_SyncFuture simulateResponse = new SalesProcessingResponse.SalesOrderSimulateResponse_SyncFuture();
public SalesProcessingResponse.SalesOrderSimulateResponse_Sync result = new SalesProcessingResponse.SalesOrderSimulateResponse_Sync();

//action method
public continuation simulate(){
    /**** custom Validations
    ----
    -----
    ------ ***/
    Integer TIMEOUT_INT_SECS = 60;  
    Continuation cont = new Continuation(TIMEOUT_INT_SECS);
    cont.continuationMethod = 'processSimulateResponse';
    //request variable - WSDL generated wrapper class type
    SalesProcessingRequest.SalesOrderSimulateRequest_Sync inputrequest = new SalesProcessingRequest.SalesOrderSimulateRequest_Sync();
    //Utility method - returns the request populated as per the need
    inputrequest = requestService.returnOrderSimulateRequest(acct, currentOrder,lstOlItems);
    simulateResponse = service.beginSalesOrderSimulate(cont, inputrequest);
    return cont;   
}
public Object processSimulateResponse(){    
       result = simulateResponse.getValue();
       system.debug('**** result'+result);
       // Return null to re-render the original Visualforce page
       return null; 
    }
```

Could anyone please let me know if there's a workaround for this?

Thanks,
Sirisha Kodi

Comment: usually, if there is a workaround it'll be included in the issue... It doesn't look like there is one. If you post some code I am sure I (or anybody else) can give you suggestions to address the calls differently.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Until the Known Issue [Apex Continuation is causing "Unable to restore input value state - state value missing for component..." when using custom component within apex:repe](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YsYAAU) is resolved your easiest option could be to move away from using the continuation to perform the callout. Instead use the direct blocking callout.

Answer (score 0):

all the corresponding outputText,outputLabel fields should have value attribute.
Even though there is no value to be assigned just give a null value
Example:
apex:outputText value=" ">